# Change elements css based on url multiple times without reloading page (AJAX needed)

Tags: jquery, css, ajax

I'm trying to add conditionality to a "Search Filters Section" of a Wordpress theme (this is why the selectors I'm using are not straightforward).

There is a dropdown with options (they are taxonomies, called "tipo-de-montaje" in english "types-of-seating"), and I need to make elements appear according to the dropdown value.

The catch seems that what I'm trying to do works once, then when another option from dropdown is selected, I would need to reload the page in order to hide the current element and show the new one.

1st question would be if I absolutely need AJAX in the first place?

Here's my 2nd attempt:

```
//Get the value of the selected option (from a dropdown)
var montajeVal = $('input[name="tipos-de-montaje"]').val();
//The containers of the elements that will be shown or hidden
const escuelaMax = $('[data-name="max-capacidad-escuela"]').parent();
const auditorioMax = $('[data-name="max-capacidad-auditorio"]').parent();
//First, they are hidden  
escuelaMax.hide();
auditorioMax.hide();
//Now, show the correct one
if (montajeVal == "escuela") {
        escuelaMax.show();
        auditorioMax.hide();
} else if (montajeVal == "auditorio")  {
        escuelaMax.hide();
        auditorioMax.show();
}
//This works only one time :(

//Maybe the JSON should contain data which $montajeVal should be compare with, check that in a loop and then accomplish what I tried to do in the IF statement above
// JSON would be just: ['escuela', 'auditorio']
//I'm using just 2 values for keeping it simple, but in reality there are more.
```

Answer (score 0):

For dynamic loading you need **AJAX** (as you've written). For the **AJAX** you need:
1. Code that initiates the **AJAX** call on the frontend (prepares and sends the request)

2. Code that handles the request on **server side** (receives the request, authenticates, validates, prepares the data to be sent back and send it back to the frontend)
3. Code that handles the dynamically received data on the frontend

In a snippet I cannot really create code that should be on your server (as no server data, coding language, etc.) was given, but **1.** and **2.** can be shown - so I try to mock your data and function.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  // this "load-data" is not supposed to be in your code -
  // an event based on URL load should be here
  $('.load-data').on('click', async function() {
    const type = $(this).attr('data-name')
    const capacity = await getCapacity(type)
    toggleDisplay(type, capacity.length)
  })
});

// code mocking getting the capacity of a theater or
// a banquet (posts and users in this code)
function getCapacity(type) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    fetch(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/${type}`)
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(json => resolve(json))
  })
}

// this function can be written shorter if the data-name
// properties match the requested item's real type (like
// theaters and banquets)
function toggleDisplay(type, capacity) {
  if (type === 'posts') {
    jQuery('#theater-container').show()
    jQuery('#banquet-container').hide()
    jQuery('#theater-container').find('[data-name="theater-capacity"]').text(capacity)
  } else {
    jQuery('#theater-container').hide()
    jQuery('#banquet-container').show()
    jQuery('#banquet-container').find('[data-name="banquet-capacity"]').text(capacity)
  }
}
```

```css
[id*="container"] {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="load-data" data-name="posts">Theaters</button><br />
<button class="load-data" data-name="users">Banquets</button>
<div id="theater-container">
  <h2>Theater capacity</h2>
  <div data-name="theater-capacity"></div>
</div>

<div id="banquet-container">
  <h2>Banquet capacity</h2>
  <div data-name="banquet-capacity"></div>
</div>
```

As the snippet is not customized to your data source it can only help you see the process of solution. The biggest difference is loading data on **click** compared to your loading data on **URL change** - but as I read you figured that out.

Comment: Thank you @muka, Your answer helped me a lot. I did some research and I updated my answer. I'm not sure what the JSON file should contain, I mentioned what I think at the end of my answer. Sorry, first approach to AJAX.